# How to load data from a sharedPreference into a ListView row?

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I came across two problems.

1) How do I get my row.xml to show in my listview.xml?

In my java class I extend ListActivity and use the code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<?> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<?>(this, R.layout.row
```

I'm not sure how to finish this.

2)  How do I load data I saved on my sharedPReference which is two string values into my row?

My code that saves the two stringvalues is:

```
String product = "Health Vitamins";
String category = "Nutrition";
savePreference("NAME", product);
savePreference("NUTRITION", category);
```

Then I use putString(key, value) and commit() in my savePreference method. When I want to load the data I simply use loadPreference() which will use getString("NAME", "") and getString("NUTRITION", "") and retrieve the data.

Problem is how do I actually put the data I retrieve into my listview row.xml? For example once loadPreference() method is invoked it is suppose to retrieve the two string values and place it in the row? Any Ideas?

Comment: Pull the data out of SharedPreferences and put it in the the String[] you are passing to ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Hey thanks for advice. I'm still a bit confused do you mind showing a small representation of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] data = //load the array here.  

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);
```

Whatever you want to put into your array. It could be your Shared Preference values. But then why would you be using Shared Preferences since it uses key value pairs. And you can't double up on keys meaning your list will always have 1 or at most 2 entries.

Comment: THe key will not always be NAME. It will be the name of the product for example, LOTION, SOAP, SHAMPOO, TOOTHPASTE.

Comment: Hey I can't get it to work. Basically I have an ArrayList<String> defined in another class which in short saves the name of the class activity into a string file. The string value is the name of the class and these are the items in the arrayList(); I'm basically trying to retrieve this arraylist() which has the saved sharedPreferences product and category. How would I get it to display all the items (the products)in a listview? My ultimate goal is to create a history activity which shows the past 10 activities that were previously the current activity. Please Help if you can?

Comment: Are you able to store this array of Strings in an object you can pass around? Where and when is it populated with data? You could also easily do this with an internal database using SQLite

Comment: Yes I store it in an object and pass it around. It populates whenever a new activity starts (this saves the activity as a string). I think I will try the SQLite approach.

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass data to ListView from SharedPreferences using Intent**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private EditText nameEditText, rollEditText, deptEditText, semesterEditText;
private Button submittButton;
private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.nameEditTextID);
    rollEditText = findViewById(R.id.rollEditTextID);
    deptEditText = findViewById(R.id.deptEditTextID);
    semesterEditText = findViewById(R.id.semesterEditTextID);
    submittButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButtonID);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewID);


    submittButton.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.submitButtonID) {

        String userName = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        String userRoll = rollEditText.getText().toString();
        String userDept = deptEditText.getText().toString();
        String userSemester = semesterEditText.getText().toString();

        if (userName.equals("") && userRoll.equals("") && userDept.equals("") && userSemester.equals("")) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Details", 0);
            //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("userNameKey", userName);
            editor.putString("userRollKey", userRoll);
            editor.putString("userDeptKey", userDept);
            editor.putString("userSemesterKey", userSemester);
            editor.apply();
            nameEditText.setText("");
            rollEditText.setText("");
            deptEditText.setText("");
            semesterEditText.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (sharedPreferences.contains("userNameKey") && sharedPreferences.contains("userRollKey") && sharedPreferences.contains("userDeptKey")
                    && sharedPreferences.contains("userSemesterKey")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }





            /*if (sharedPreferences.contains("userNameKey") && sharedPreferences.contains("userRollKey") && sharedPreferences.contains("userDeptKey")
                    && sharedPreferences.contains("userSemesterKey")) {


                String name = sharedPreferences.getString("userNameKey", "Data not found");
                String roll = sharedPreferences.getString("userRollKey", "Data not found");
                String department = sharedPreferences.getString("userDeptKey", "Data not found");
                String semester = sharedPreferences.getString("userSemesterKey", "Data not found");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                textView.setText(name + "\n" + roll + "\n" + department + "\n" + semester);
            }*/


        }


    }


}
```

public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_data);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewID);


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Details", 0);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("userNameKey", "Data not found");
    String roll = sharedPreferences.getString("userRollKey", "Data not found");
    String department = sharedPreferences.getString("userDeptKey", "Data not found");
    String semester = sharedPreferences.getString("userSemesterKey", "Data not found");

   Toast.makeText(this, "Roll is:" + roll, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(name);
    arrayList.add(roll);
    arrayList.add(department);
    arrayList.add(semester);
    ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.sampleTextViewID,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




}
```

}